# Scrolling a UITableView inside a UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, ipad, uiscrollview

I have a `UITableView` which is a subview of a `UIView`, then that `UIView` is a subview of a `UIScrollView`. How do I detect the touches that should scroll the `UITableView`?

The `UITableView` can get item selection events (a cell in the table is selected/tapped) just fine, except that you have to hold down on the cell before it fires. But I can't get the `UITableView` to scroll, its always the `UIScrollView` that reacts to the pan gesture.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Solved, though I asked the wrong question. It does work by default as Roman K pointed out. I think the problem was related to having a part of the `UITableView` outside the bounds of the `UIScrollView` (the `UITableView` went over the bottom bounds of the `UIScrollView`). Setting it to correctly fit inside the `UIScrollView` fixed it.

Comment: i would like to suggest this answer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422915/scrolling-a-uitableview-inside-a-uiscrollview/32486714#32486714

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Please, make sure that `UIScrollView's` properties `delaysContentTouches` and `canCancelContentTouches` are set appropriately. They control how UIScrollView instance passes touch information to its subviews. By default `delaysContentTouches` is set to YES. Also, make sure that, if you extended `UIScrollView`, `touchesShouldBegin:withEvent:inContentView:` allow touches in the subview.

Otherwise, `UITableView` scrolling should work by default in your scenario. If you create a test project with just the view hierarchy as described you will see that it is the case. So, compare the two and see what difference affects the scrolling.

Comment: I believe I set delaysContentTouches (set to YES) and canCancelContentTouches (set to NO) just fine. I am able to get taps in the UITableView just fine, but not swipes and pans.

Comment: I think this logic got broken in iOS8. Looks like UIScrollView will intercept vertical scroll gestures and not ignore them. I posted a new question about it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25558630/uiscrollview-behavior-is-different-in-ios8

Comment: @sha +1 We have having the same exact issue!