# UITableView Scroll when touch starts on subview

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

i have a tableview with different kind of cells, one of which has some UITextFields's and UIButton. When i try to scroll this view with the touch starting in any of those subviews the table won't scroll and recognizes it as a 'touch inside' of a subview. I had it before with "delays content touches'  but the touch inside button doesn't work well. Any ideas how i might fix this problem?

I just found i had an 'UITapGestureRecognizer' that was creating the problem. thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

Turning off "Cancellable Content Touches" in the UITableView solved this for me (in the UITableView attributes inspector under Scroll View / Touch). I got this from this SO question: [Scrolling a UITableView inside a UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422915/scrolling-a-uitableview-inside-a-uiscrollview)

From the UIScrollView:canCancelContentTouches doc:

If the value of this property is NO, the scroll view does not scroll regardless of finger movement once the content view starts tracking.

Comment: hmm i checked but doesn't work... what i need is something like: when touching on subviews if it's a touch inside let subview handle it, if its a drag let the table view handle it for scrolling. Turning off that flag just turns off the scroll at all

Comment: Other thing i forgot to mention... it that my original problem was that with the 'delay content touches'  if ou give a fast click on the button it won't work. you have to give a lonnggg click or click inside the button and drag the mouse outside