# Adding a collection or tableview or custom view to a scrollview in ios 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have a UIScrollView with lots of sub views on the scrollview.  I have a picture, buttons, textfields and the like that all work fine.

Now I want to add a comment section below all this that "acts" like a UITableView.

What is the best way to accomplish this? I want the comment section to load 10 comments when that part of the view appears, and continually add 10 more comments when the 6th comment appears.  There should also be an activity indicator too.

I know you can't put a collection view or tableview with a scrollview (according to Apple) as their are inherited from UIScrollView. And making the whole view controller a table view or collection view is tough since I have so many subviews and actions all linked up already.

What's the best approach?

Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to add the UITableView to the scrollview like any other UIView subclass.

Comment: No you shouldn't do that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17121488/how-to-use-uitableview-inside-uiscrollview-and-receive-a-cell-click

Comment: put tableview inside scrollview.. whats a problem?

Answer (score -1):

You can create a new table view controller and load (add subview on cell content view) your current controller as first cell of table view controller.