# UITableView embedded in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I am trying to embed a table view into a scroll view. I would like the scrolling to happen on the scroll view level. I am able to embed the table view into the scroll view but I am stuck at trying to resize the scroll view content size to fit the full height of the table view..how can I achieve this?

Comment: Did you search SO yet?  Quite a few answers.  The answers given on this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17121488/how-to-use-uitableview-inside-uiscrollview-and-receive-a-cell-click look legit to me

Comment: It says that Apple advises against it but Instagram does it in their profile screen...I'm trying to mimic that @danh

Comment: It may not mimic instagram exactly, but a UIPageViewController whose pages contain tables would provide the 2D scrolling effect that it sounds like you'd like.  And its 100% kosher relative to how the sdk works

Comment: I don't think Instagram puts a table view in s scroll view. I think they either use a collection view or a regular old table view and set the header to be the info at the top of the profile. You'll have a much better experience if you go that direction.

Comment: I think you're right @gurooj !! After taking a second look at it that does make much more sense

Comment: @MikeSimz you'll have much better scrolling performance if you use the header or footer of a table view or collection view. Or just make the first cell be different and contain the header view inside a regular cell. Both classes are very flexible for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

you can calculate tableview height in `heightForFooterInSection` or `viewForFooterInSection`  of table

```
_tblOption.scrollEnabled = NO;
Frame = _tblOption.frame;
Frame.size.height = _tblOption.contentSize.height;
_tblOption.frame = Frame;

_mainScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(_mainScrollView.contentSize.width, _tblOption.frame.origin.y + _tblOption.contentSize.height);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your hierarchy should be as follow: `UIView` -> `UIScrollView` -> `UITableView`. That mean you simple create UIViewController, then place UIScrollView, connect delegates and so forth, then place in it UITableView controller.

But im wonder why would you put `tableView` inside scroll view, better design would be place separately `UITableView` and `UIScrollView`.

I much rather recommend you to have UIView with UITableView AND UIScrollView, placed separately.

In XCode you may use Editor->Embed In.

Comment: I want it like this because this is how Instagram designed their Profile screen by the looks of it.

Comment: Okay, there is UIScrollView + UICoillectionView and UIScrollView + UITableView, but their are placed separately as i told you.

Comment: I don't believe they are placed separately because they scroll all as one..nonetheless, after taking another look I believe it is just a single table view and the personal info at the top is simply the header of the table view

Comment: @MikeSimz ok, please check this project (its not mine though) and go through implementation of Views (when i made my instagramm app i place it separately as well ) - https://github.com/8ofproject/ElPhotoSnooper