# Tableview does not appeared Until setting a tableFooterView

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, scrollview

Here is a example for UItableview within scrollview using autolayout. It works well. But if I remove tableFooterView from UItableview, the UItableview is disppeared.

I want to know why tableview need a tableFooterView here? thank you.

the following is source code :

`MyTableView.m` file:

```
@implementation MyTableView
- (CGSize)intrinsicContentSize {
    [self layoutIfNeeded];
    return CGSizeMake(UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric, self.contentSize.height);
}
@end
```

`ViewController.m` file:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "MyTableView.h"

@interface ViewController ()<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
@end

@implementation ViewController
- (void)loadView {
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
    self.view = view;

    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor cyanColor];
    [view addSubview:scrollView];

    UITableView *tableView = [[MyTableView alloc] init];
    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    tableView.dataSource = self;
    tableView.delegate = self;
    [scrollView addSubview:tableView];

    //why have to need this ?
    tableView.tableFooterView = [[UILabel alloc] init];

    //add constraint
    NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings( scrollView,   tableView );
    [view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-30-[scrollView]-30-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
    [view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[scrollView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

    [view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[tableView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
    [view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[tableView]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
    [view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:tableView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1 constant:0]];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 20;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Row %d", indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
@end
```

Comment: Why do you put your tableview inside a scrollview ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very bad approach. Do not use uitableview inside uiscrollView. See details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17121582/2382237)

Shortly,

> You should not embed UIWebView or UITableView objects in UIScrollView
>   objects. If you do so, unexpected behavior can result because touch
>   events for the two objects can be mixed up and wrongly handled.

So, this problem belongs to what Apple said  - unexpected behavior

You may rewrite your code as, for example:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
        UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
        self.view = view;

        UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        tableView.dataSource = self;
        tableView.delegate = self;
        [view addSubview:tableView];
        //add constraint
        NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(   tableView );

        [view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[tableView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
        [view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[tableView]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
        [view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:tableView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1 constant:0]];

    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        return 20;
    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        if (!cell) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        }
        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Row %d", indexPath.row];
        return cell;
    }
```

If you still want to add uitableview - your constraints setted up in a wrong way. You should add tableview's constraints  to uiscrollview, not uiview, and also add equal height constraint to table view

replace your constraints code with:

```
NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings( scrollView,   tableView );
    [view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-30-[scrollView]-30-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
    [view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[scrollView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

    [scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[tableView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
    [scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[tableView]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
    [view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:tableView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1 constant:0]];
    [view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:tableView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1 constant:0]];
```

Comment: @stackfisher, mark it as answer, please, if it was useful for you :)