# Adding a UIView on the bottom of a TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, uiscrollview

I have a tableView ("tableView") with a UIScrollView (when the user scrolls the tableView changing its position), I want that when the user "over-scrolls" the tableView up, there will be a white UIView ("whiteViewUnderAroundersTableView") that goes from the bottom of the tableView, an example of the scroll:
[scroll example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NMOR.png)

My code:

```
//Creating "whiteViewFrame", a frame for "whiteViewUnderTableView"(a white view in the scrollView that goes behind the "tableView" and shows a white view when Over-Scrolling up) with the Y position of the end of the "tableView"
CGRect whiteViewFrame=CGRectMake(self.whiteViewUnderTableView.frame.origin.x, CGRectGetMaxY(self.tableView.frame), self.whiteViewUnderTableView.frame.size.width, self.whiteViewUnderTableView.frame.size.height);

//Changing "whiteViewUnderTableView"'s frame to "whiteViewFrame"
self.whiteViewUnderTableView.frame=whiteViewFrame;

//Changing "whiteViewUnderAroundersTableViewTopConstraint" (Y coordinate constraint of "whiteViewUnderAroundersTableView")'s constant to "AroundersTableView"'s Y coordinate
self.whiteViewUnderAroundersTableViewTopConstraint.constant=self.whiteViewUnderAroundersTableView.frame.origin.y;
```

The error in the log:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
Try this: 
    (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
    (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it...
```

Comment: why don't you create custom cell with your last view and show it at the end?

Comment: you didn't post the whole error in the log!!!

Comment: Even better than a custom cell, there is a `tableFooterView` property which should work for you. Or a footer view for last section of your table.

Comment: where r u adding the code/

Answer (score 0):

The `tableView` is a sub-class of `UIScrollView`, so it is not necessary to add a `tableView` as a child view of `UIScrollView`. When you set the `delegate` of a `tableView`, the `delegate` is for `UITableViewDelegate`, and it is also for `UIScrollViewDelegate`.

Moreover, you can add a custom view as a `tableFooterView` property of tableView. The `tableFooterView` will put on the bottom of `tableView`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're saying correctly, in general you should not embed a tableView in a scrollView to accomplish this goal. When you do this, iOS has no way to tell if a swipe up/down was intended for the tableview or the scrollview since they are both scrollable!

Per: [How to use UITableView inside UIScrollView and receive a cell click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17121488/how-to-use-uitableview-inside-uiscrollview-and-receive-a-cell-click)

tableFooterView is a much better option:

```
tableView.tableFooterView = UIView( ... )
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply call this 2 delegate methods

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{

return 60;
```

}

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{
CGRect frame = tableView.frame;
frame.size.height = 60;

UIView *footerView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
footerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor brownColor];

return footerView;
```

}