# a UITableView is embeded in a UIScrollView, swipe to delete is not work

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I try a lot methods but not get solution

In my case, my view hierarchy:

```
UIView
  UIScrollView
  LeftContainer + RightContainer
                (in RihgtContainer) ViewContainer 
                                      TableView
```

[image]

I tried these:

subclassing Scrollview and

```
 - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self.nextResponder touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   if(!self.dragging)
    {
        [self.nextResponder touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
    }
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self.nextResponder touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
```

}

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer


innerTableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
innerTableView.alwaysBounceVertical = NO;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tray to set the `delaysTouchesBegan` to `true` on your scrollview... like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/31040918/1702413

**but** .. 
`UITableview` is inherited from  `UIScrollView`

You should not embed `UIWebView` or `UITableView` objects in `UIScrollView` objects https://stackoverflow.com/a/17121582/1702413