# UITableView didSelect delegate doesnt gets called?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, didselectrowatindexpath

In my app, I have added an UITableView over a ScrollView. I have **disabled** scrolling in table view. 
So, only the scrollView Scrolls, I have adjusted the scroll view content Size with the tableView Frame. So, I can access all the cells.

Consider, there are 5 rows visible in the screen, if I tap any of the row, the **didSelectRowAtIndexPath** method gets called. If I scroll down, say to 6th cell and tap on it. The method doesnt gets called.

Same issues happens with UIcollectionView.

The reason why I have added so is. When I scroll the Scroll View, a view in that should get fixed in the top and the tableView behind it should go on scrolling. You might have seen in many of the apps in Android. So, I have used the ScrollView didScroll delegate to get the offset position. As per it, I will make the view to be fixed and vice versa.

Comment: What is height of tableview?

Comment: Why do you have a uitableview inside a scrollview ?

Comment: For my design, I need to do so. I have customized some functions like in android.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17121488/how-to-use-uitableview-inside-uiscrollview-and-receive-a-cell-click . You can refer to this thread.

Comment: Ya, saw it. Thanks bro. Let me edit my question as per my requirement.

Comment: check that clips to bounds property is true for view and scrollview and also apply background colour and see the borders

Comment: @MikeAlter, If I do so, The tableView content which appears below the screen, disappears. How can I clear it.

Comment: your content is  disappears because it is clips to superview , in simple words your view size is small that's why it disappears, you can check same by apply different colours and check frame ...

Comment: I cleared the issuw. While changing the values in the table dynamically, I tried to chnage the height of the Table, now, I created a constant for height contraint and changed it . It worked. Thanks guys. Especially @MikeAlter

Comment: Just another thought: did you know, that a UITableView is a UIScrollView subclass? So if you create a UITableView and set the delegate, it will also call the scrollViewDidScroll method, with the tableView as a parameter, and it will have contentSize and contentOffset. So maybe you can just get rid of the scrollView itself, to keeps things simpler.

Comment: most wlcm @BalachandarMutharasu

Comment: YA @romeouald, I have set Tag for each Views and used conditions in appropriate places.

Answer (score 0):

Make the height of `UITableView` same as the content height of table.
Then set the content size of `UIScrollView` as the height of `UITableView`

Here is a brief example to demonstrate

```
CGRect rect = tblTopics.frame;
rect.size.height = tblTopics.contentSize.height;
tblTopics.frame = rect;

self.scrlVwFacultyDtl.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrlVwFacultyDtl.frame.size.width, tblTopics.frame.size.height);
```

In the above example the tblTopics is the instance of `UITableView` and scrlVwFacultyDtl is the instance of `UIScrollView`

hope it will help you..

Comment: Thanks bro, I got it. With the help of the comments. I just changes the height constraints dynamically.