# Xcode: ScrollView and not scrollable TableView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a table view that has scrolling disabled and I can add items to it. Above and beneath it are a few other controls. The problem is, when the table view gets too many items, the content is out of screen.

To solve this I think I need a scroll view but it needs to wrap the whole content and needs to be dynamic in height. How can I do this?

Edit: Maybe this makes the question simpler: I need to have a scrollView, that basically wraps the content. The content is a table View, that varies in height and some buttons.

Comment: This will be a bad idea!

Comment: `UITableView` is a `UIScrollView` subclass. It's not recommended to embed a `UIScrollView` within a `UIScrollView` because of the difficulty of managing the touch events.

Comment: I don't know if I have understand but look [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619383-alwaysbouncevertical)

Comment: Why is this a bad idea? I have disabled the scrolling of the tableView, I want just the ScrollView to scroll so there is not "scrolling conflict"...

Comment: @Kerberos Thanks but I don't think this is what I was looking for

Comment: @Jonas setting the property to yes you can lock the scroll of the tableview only if all the cells are visible.

Comment: @Kerberos I already have locked the scrolling of the tableView. What I want to do is have a ScrollView, that wraps this tableView, so I can scroll this ScrollView instead of the tableView

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17121488/how-to-use-uitableview-inside-uiscrollview-and-receive-a-cell-click for some reasons why this is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

i think you must make an autolayout
try this steps
1- Set view constraint (top, bottom, leading and trailing) as (0,0,0,0).
2- Now you can see hierarchy like this view -> scroll view -> view(content view).

3- Now we need add more constraint for content view.

- Most important step *

4 - Our content view must have equal width and equal height with parent view.

Now select height constraint of content view and set priority with low(250).

5- We are done with our setup.
6- Now you can design your view with any height.

Comment: Im not sure If I understand you correctly. You mean a hierarchy like this: View -> Scroll View ->(Content View:) View -> (Content:)TableView and Buttons. Then the content View should have a height constraint?

Comment: never use tableview inside scroll view

Comment: Can you say why I shouldn't do that?

Comment: because apple say not to use ...according to apple guide lines, tableview shouldn't be added to scrollView. App may likely be rejected by apple. So its better if you only use tableview

Comment: Ah ok thats a good reason, thank you. But still how could I do it, so that for example a Button and a TextField scroll at once?