# UITableView inside UIScrollViews

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a `UITableView` inside vertically scrolled (with paging enabled) `UIScrollView`. I don't like the default behaviour and I would like to change it:

- by default when `UITableView` is scrolled to top or bottom (one of the edges) the vertical drag up (when at bottom) or vertical drag down (when at top) is propagated to parent `UIScrollView`.

Is there any way I could prevent this kind of a behaviour? I would like to stop propagation whenever the drag finger move is started in `UITableView` frame.

I was looking at Apple notes about nested `UIScrollView`s but couldn't find any useful information there.

Comment: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422915/scrolling-a-uitableview-inside-a-uiscrollview)

Answer (score 0):

you can prevent it just disabling bouncing of your scroll view, to set the bounce policy you can edit your nib file or controlling those properties:

```
@property bounces
@property alwaysBounceVertical
@property alwaysBounceHorizontal
```

Comment: It is almost what i would like to achieve - sometimes when i drag the tableview outer scrollview is scrolled - I can't understand the "rule" that covers this kind of behaviour. Also, I would like to get "bounce" behaviour when draggin without the "bounce" effect :-)

Comment: UITableView is a scroll view as well, so you can play with bounce both scrollview and to achieve the result that you want