# UIScrollView that has UITableViews as subviews won't scroll horizontally

Tags: uitableview, ios7, uiscrollview, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a view controller that owns a `UISegmentedControl`, a `UIScrollView`, and several `UITableView`s. The segmented control and the scroll view are subviews of the view controller's root view. The table views are subviews of the scroll view. The scroll view takes up all the space below the segmented control and each table view is as large as the scroll view. Table views are placed horizontally aligned inside the scroll view.

The view controller should support scrolling to one of its table views either by selection in the segmented control (that works) or by swipe gesture (that does not work yet). I have checked that the scroll view's `contentSize` is appropriate and I have also tried turning the table view cells' `userInteractionEnabled` off. I have also checked that the table views do not exceed the size of the scroll view as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17974154/uitableview-scrolling-problems-when-inside-a-uiscrollview). (Each table view is as large as the scroll view, albeit at a horizontal offset.) Still the scroll view can|t be swiped horizontally as I would expect.

Could it be that the table views themselves consume all (including horizontal) swipe gestures as part of their support for vertical scrolling? How can I ensure that the scroll view further up in the scroll hierarchy can (also) react to such swipe gestures?

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765661/gesture-problem-uiswipegesturerecognizer-uislider)

Comment: Also [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422915/scrolling-a-uitableview-inside-a-uiscrollview)