# Scrolling issue when UITableView is inside ScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, scrollview

I have a `UIScrollview` covering the entire `UIViewController`'s main view. Inside `UIScrollview` is a content view that allows the `UIScrollview` get the scrollable content. Inside the Content View of Scroll View is a `UITableView`. 
I'm not being able to scroll the `UITableView`. Instead the vertical swipe is passed directly to the ScrollView causing it to scroll. How can I make the `UITableView` scroll inside the `UIScrollview`?

I have read the answers of many similar questions but none of them solved my issue

[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422915/scrolling-a-uitableview-inside-a-uiscrollview/32486714#32486714)

[Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17974154/uitableview-scrolling-problems-when-inside-a-uiscrollview)

[Question 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33292427/how-to-make-the-scroll-of-a-tableview-inside-scrollview-behave-naturally)

Comment: Have you found any good solution?

Comment: @Snoobie yes I did. I stopped using scrollView all together and instead used a static TableView with cell having another tableView. UITableView is the most powerful tool in Swift. Use it when you can.

Comment: I solved it too with another method, it's little tricky but I catch SwipeGesture and TapGesture in aim to active or not the scroll of my main ScrollView. Thank you by the way !

Answer (score 0):

You need to set correct constraints (or frames) for `UITableView` (size of TableView must be less, then contentSize for scrolling).

Comment: My TableView size is less than contentSize

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure that's your constraints of UITableView related to UiScrollView
- Disable UITableView scrolling
- Make your scollView center Verticly to the main container and change the priority of constraint to 999

Hope that help you