# UIScrollView behavior is different in iOS8

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiscrollview, ios8

I have the following layout

[image]

So it's basically a scroll view that occupies whole screen. Content size is set to triple-width and same height. Inside the scroll view - there is container view and three table views - one per page. Only middle table view is visible initially.

This allows me to use scroll view horizontal scrolling to navigate between the tables and vertical scrolling inside the middle table.

I know that Apple doesn't really recommend putting UITableView inside UIScrollView, but in this particular case I don't know how to implement it differently, and until iOS8 everything was working fine.

UIScrollView would not recognize any vertical scrolling (since content height was equal to scroll view height) and these gestures were passed directly to UITableView.

But starting in iOS8 - this getting broken. UIScrollView would allow some vertical scrolling and basically intercept scrolling gestures sent to UITableView.

I created a simple project that works fine in iOS7 but is broken in iOS8. Anybody has any idea how to fix this problem?

Link to the project: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6402890/TablePaging.zip

Comment: We are in the exact same boat. Worked fine in prior to iOS 8. Now its broken. Did you find anything out about this??

Comment: Not yet. Will work today with GM seed

Comment: Sounds good. I will post back here if I figure anything out. Thanks.

Comment: I could not figure out what's wrong with the old approach. But looks like replacing this manual UIScrollView with UIPageViewController will work and work properly in both iOS7/8.

Comment: This is what I ended up resolving too also. Seems like a cleaner approach compared to tableviews inside a scrollview.

Comment: Even though that tableview inside the scrollview is exactly what you get when you use UIPageViewController. I checked the view hierarchy there and it's almost identical to what I manually created. The only difference is they use internal _UIQueueScrollView or something like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't been able to solve this and as I mentioned in comments had to re-write logic using built-in `UIPageViewController` class.

Answer (score 0):

If I change the Class of your `ScrollView` in Interface Builder to `UIScrollView`, it fixes part of the problem. Now just the `UITableView` goes up and down, and I go left-and-right, but haven't gotten rid of the space at the top.

[image]